# SAS create matrix of intersection of variables' values

Tags: matrix, sas, transpose

guys,

I'm trying to create a matrix of the form

```
    x1   x2   x3

x1  12   14   22

x2   1    0    0

x3  10    0    5
```

from the dataset of the form

```
id_of_observation     x1    x2    x3
```

i.e. have values ('A' or 'B') of 3 variables and I want to find out how many observations have intersection of x1 = 'B' and x2 = 'B' simultaneously, x1 = 'B' and x3 = 'B' simultaneously, and so on for all possible intersections.

Any help with this task is highly appreciated.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what needs to be done here. Can you add more context and any SAS code of what you have already tried?

Comment: If I understand the question, this is what `proc freq` is for.

Comment: Are you using SAS-IML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @Jeff for the hint:

Try something like this:

```
data source;
length ID 8;
input X1 $1. X2 $1. X3 $1.;
ID = _N_;
cards;
AAA
AAB
ABB
ABA
;
run;

proc freq data=source  noprint;
tables x1 * x2* x3 / nocum nopercent out=counts;
run;

proc sql;
select
      X1=X2 as X1_X2
    , X1=X3 as X1_X3
    , X2 = X3 as X2_X3
    , count(*) as _count
 from counts
    group by 1,2,3
;
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked pretty well for me!